# C++ zip library that supports encryption

Tags: c++, encryption, zip, cross-platform

the project that am developing need a cross-platform zip library in c++ that meets these things:

1: Could be used in commercial project without any charge. No external dll as a bonus.

2: Cross-platform (Windows,Linux,MacOS)

3: Supports encryption.

I use it only for zipping/unzipping some text script files with encryption,so the files are really small(total less than 1MB). Users could copy the zip freely, but they can't get the script files inside. I don't even care if it is a zip file or other compression file type, other rarely used formats will be totally fine. I just wanna pack and encrypt my data.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use OpenSSL. 
I've used it for several projects and its good. Has decent C++ built-in libraries, which are easy to use and are obviously free. Also works on Windows on Linux (I've worked with both, not sure about MAC though).
https://www.openssl.org/
you will find all the instructions and downloads needed here on the website. You might require some extra guides if you wanna import that libraries within editors like Visual Studio.
Also if you want to compile in linux, all you have to do is type `-lcrypto` within the makefile.

example of makefile within linux:

```
all: Source

Source:Source.o
    g++ -o Source Source.o -lcrypto 
Source.o: Source.cpp
    g++ -c Source.cpp
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Dani, but what about the zip library?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "zip" libraries, I'm not familiar with the term and neither did looking it up help me realize  what you are talking about. I'm sure the Openssl website will help you out with that if you believe you know what you talking about. I've heard some use [Keyczar](https://code.google.com/p/keyczar/wiki/CppTutorial) which is also another way of encrypting in c++.
Hope this helps